# Searching a template for thesis APA

Tags: templates, apa-style

I've been looking online for several hours and I have not found a template in APA thesis in Latex. I wonder if you have any template you can share me, or any idea of where to look.

Here I have a [Template in Microsoft Word](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCUQFjABahUKEwimuNa8wNHIAhUM2B4KHc_vCjg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ubalt.edu%2Fcas%2Fgraduate-programs-and-certificates%2Fdegree-programs%2Finteraction-design-and-information-architecture%2FThesis_Template.docx&usg=AFQjCNFcbSh3IkpOdAHnpbiSuQCiKNWFHA&sig2=tytxXvoubew9WaTTIhSVKw&cad=rja) that can be used as a guide for comparison.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that you will not find such a template.  I went the University of Baltimore thesis webpage and noted that they only offer a Word Template.  Before you use LaTeX for the thesis, I would recommend that you personally verify that this will be acceptable for submission (I would also recommend that you get this decision in writing, as sometimes during the progress of an advanced degree key decision makers move to new positions, and the new decision maker will not have any knowledge of verbal agreements).  If LaTeX is to be used then expect to have to personally build the correct style.

Comment: @R.Schumacher The truth, I think so. So I went to the users who may already have developed. I will develop my work in Word, and then propose a template in Latex.

Comment: To the extent that the thesis document follows the actual APA style exactly then it may be possible to tweak the APA6 class to do this. But in fact APA style isn't so difficult to emulate, so I would recommend using a documentclass like `memoir` or `scrbook` and defining things by hand.  Then you can use `biblatex-apa` for your bibliography, since it is the most up-to-date APA bibliography system I know.

Comment: Didn't APA say, that they don't have any guidelines for thesis? On the other hand, there is http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/11/dissertation-helpers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started using this template available from [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/your-apa6-style-manuscript/kngbbqpypjcq#.Via1tX4rLIU).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0):

LyX has an APA6 template (File > New from Template > APA6.lyx). I'll paste the exported LaTeX here:

```
%% LyX 2.2.0dev created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,jou]{apa6}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.

\journal{Journal of Important Stuff}
\volume{Vol. 0 (2007), pp.\textasciitilde{}1\textendash 22}
\ccoppy{© The Author}
\copnum{ISSN XXX-XXXX-XXXX}
\providecommand{\LyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{Long Title of the Paper Which is Very Descriptive of the Work Being
Done}

\shorttitle{Short Title of Paper}

\author{Author Name}

\leftheader{Author}

\affiliation{Big Name University\\
Department of Psychology}

\note{Draft of 12/ 16/12.}

\abstract{This the abstract for my document. The purpose of this document is
to demonstrate the new apa6 class that I have been working on. There
was a layout file for the original apa document class which was authored
by Randy Gobbel. This document is based on that layout, but includes
many additions and updates. I really don't like having relevant information
in a preamble if it is not necessary. So, styles for all the necessary
commands have been included as part of the document instead.}

\keywords{apa6, layout, template, \LyX{}}

\authornote{We would like to acknowledge all of the many people who contributed
to this work.}
\maketitle

\section{Section Heading}

Standard text. Standard text. Standard text. Standard text. Standard
text. Standard text. Standard text. Standard text. Standard text.
Standard text. Standard text. Standard text. Standard text. Standard
text. Standard text. Standard text. Standard text. Standard text.
Standard text. Standard text. 

This is more standard text. This is more standard text. This is more
standard text. This is more standard text. This is more standard text.
This is more standard text. 

\subsection{Subsection Heading}

This is more standard text. If you use the nifty natbibapa module,
then you can select apacite as the bibliography style below. This
allows you to do awesome stuff. For example, check out this inline
citation. \citet{jame76} declared...notice that it uses ``and''
between names. Now check out this one \citep{gree00}. It uses ``\&''
between names just like it is supposed to.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the above creates a journal article, not a thesis. I'm sure there's some way to adapt it, but searching for an APA6 thesis template was how I ended up on this page.